# Fixing parameter of random effect with gamm in R

Tags: gam, mgcv

Do you know if it is possible to fit a parameter of a random effect using gamm from the mgcv package?
For example a Normal distribution N(0, c) and fix c to a certain value instead of being estimated?

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,

Bayesianboy

I searched for the documentation but could not find anything.

Comment: If you recast this as a GAM and fitted the random effect as a smooth with `s(f, bs = "re")` there you could fix the smoothing parameter for that smooth at some specified value. You'd just have to work out what value of the smoothing parameter (on the log scale I think) you want for a given standard deviation *c*, which may or may not be easy...

Comment: Thank you for your answer, the parameter c should be fixed to a very large value (e.g. 1e12). So the random effect u should follow a Gaussian distribution N(0, 1e12).